# Maven dependency when using opencsv in AEM Bundle

Tags: maven, osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, opencsv

I am trying to use opencsv in my AEM project. For that I have added the maven dependency as below in my core bundle pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
<artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
<version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But after adding this dependency, my project bundle is showing installed status and I can see the below when analysing the bundle. Unable to start my bundle.

```
org.apache.log -- Cannot be resolved

org.apache.avalon.framework.logger -- Cannot be resolved
```

Error.log :
missing requirement - Unresolved requirements: osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.log)

Can someone help me understand if we need to add any more maven dependency when using opencsv in AEM?

Comment: Yes. Adding the dependencies in import-package solved the issue